# Typing a Typescript mixin function that can be applied to both classes and instances

Tags: typescript

**TL;DR:** My function accepts either a constructor or a constructed object, mutates it, then returns it. How can I properly type the return value so that classes stay classes, objects stay objects, and both have new properties?

**Details**

I'm close: when mixed into the object, both original methods and mixed in methods are available, and when mixed into the constructor, only mixed in methods are available.

**Two problems with my current solution:**

1. When mixing in to a constructor, the type of the instance that is produced is `MixinType & typof OriginalClass` instead of `MixinType & OriginalClass` (static methods on the OriginalClass are available as instance methods, and instance methods aren't available
2. When mixing in to a constructor, the constructor has no arguments in its type signature, it has the constructor signature of `MixinTypeClass` (this isn't surprising, that's how I wrote it - that's why I'm asking this question, I'm looking for another way to do it).

**My best attempt**

```
class OriginalClass {
    instanceMethod(): void { }
}

interface MixinType {
    mixedIn(): void;
}

interface MixinTypeClass<T> {
    new (): MixinType & T;
}

function Mixin<T extends Function>(classOrInstance: T): MixinTypeClass<T>;
function Mixin<T extends Object>(classOrInstance: T): T & MixinType;
function Mixin<T extends any>(classOrInstance: T): any {
    if (typeof classOrInstance === 'function') {
        (classOrInstance.prototype as any).mixedIn = () => { }
        return classOrInstance as any as MixinTypeClass<T>;
    } else {
        (classOrInstance as any).mixedIn = () => { }
        return classOrInstance as typeof classOrInstance & MixinType;
    }
}

let NewClass = Mixin(OriginalClass);
let instance1 = new NewClass();
instance1.mixedIn();
// Property 'instanceMethod' does not exist on the type 'MixinType & typeof OriginalClass'
instance1.instanceMethod();

let instance2 = Mixin(new OriginalClass());
instance2.mixedIn();
instance2.instanceMethod();
```

**So, how can I change `Mixin` so that there is no compiler error for `instance1.instanceMethod()`?**

Answer (score 0):

Shortening your `classOrInstance` to a simple `arg`,
you can do as follows:

```
function Mixin<T extends Object>(arg: Function): MixinTypeClass<T>;
function Mixin<T extends Object>(arg: T): T & MixinType;
function Mixin<T extends Object>(arg: Function | T): any {
    if (arg instanceof Function) {
        (arg.prototype as any).mixedIn = () => { }
        return arg as MixinTypeClass<T>;
    } else {
        (arg as any).mixedIn = () => { }
        return arg as T & MixinType;
    }
}
```

This gives full intellisense and type safety in:

```
let NewClass: MixinTypeClass<OriginalClass> = Mixin<OriginalClass>(OriginalClass);
let instance1: OriginalClass & MixinType = new NewClass();
instance1.mixedIn();
instance1.instanceMethod();

let instance2: OriginalClass & MixinType = Mixin<OriginalClass>(new OriginalClass());
instance2.mixedIn();
instance2.instanceMethod();
```

It is interesting to note that `MixinTypeClass<OriginalClass>` and `OriginalClass & MixinType` are not the same.